# How to sort this response of json in a select input in angular 2 without the number in the begging?

Tags: json, angular

I have this Response

```
{
    "data": {
        "emailDigests": {
            "1": "Every 3 hours",
            "2": "Every 6 hours",
            "3": "Every 12 hours",
            "4": "Daily"
        }
    }
}
```

How to sort this response of json in a select input in angular 2 without the number in the begging?

Comment: do you mean "number in the *beginning*"?

Comment: @Gab I think he mean wihout the id or the key

Comment: @F0XS I agree, just wanted to be sure

Comment: yes i need to list the items only without keys

Answer (score 1):

You could use [keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
let d = {
    "data": {
        "emailDigests": {
            "1": "Every 3 hours",
            "2": "Every 6 hours",
            "3": "Every 12 hours",
            "4": "Daily"
        },
}
}

Object.keys(d.data.emailDigests).map(key => {
 console.log(d.data.emailDigests[key])
})
```

Comment: i already have a pipe file in my project but i dont know what i write to reach the needed result